# Applescript with terminal find and remove folders

Tags: terminal, applescript

So i want to try and make a script that will find and delete multiple folders in a folder with applescript:

```
tell application "Terminal"
    activate
    do script "find (Path to folder) -type d *-name "Foldername*" -exec rm -rf {} \;*"

end tell
```

Applescript wont run anything after *-type d* because of "Syntaxerror expected end of row" but I dont understand why because it works if i run

```
find (Path to folder) -type d *-name "Foldername*" -exec rm -rf {} \;*
```

in terminal

Comment: Is there a reason why you don't use the `do shell script` command?

Answer (score 2):

You could use the command `do shell script` which does the same thing as running it in Terminal. And you don't need a `tell` block to run this.

Also here are a two points to look at in your script.

1. If you want to use `"` quotes in your already quoted shell script then you need to escape them using `\`.
       i.e. `"some script \"some name\" some more script"`.
   Otherwise, just use single quotes in your double quoted script.
2. If you want a `\` to be **run** in your script then you need to escape it in Applescript.
       i.e. `rm -rf {} \\;*"`

Final script would look something more like this:

```
do shell script "find (Path to folder) -type d *-name 'Foldername*' -exec rm -rf {} \\;*"
```